# TypeError: snapshot.forEach is not a function at fetchData (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\stbot\index.js:152:18)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

I keep getting this error "TypeError: snapshot.forEach is not a function" when trying to read the snapshot Query Data.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because `collection.get()` returns a promise you need to use `.then` like that:

```
snapshot.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

    })
})
```